# This code keep getting else without if errors

Tags: java

This code keeps getting if without else errors. I couldn't see the problem here. Please help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempOut {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //variable
        double t;
        double v;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //inputs
        System.out.print("Give temperature(C): ");
        t = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Give wind velocity(km/h): ");
        v = input.nextDouble();

        //formula
        if (((t>=-50) & (t=<5)) | 3>=v) 
        {
            double formula = 13.12 + (2*(0.6251*t)) - (11.37*v) + ((0.3965*t)*v);
            System.out.print("The wind chill temperature is : "+formula);
        }
        else {
            if (((t<-50) & (t>5)) | v=<3) 
            {
            System.out.print("Formula not suitable");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Invalid input");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It says on every 'else' there's an error.

Comment: you used `&`instead of `&&`, `|` instead of `||`, and this `(t<-50) & (t>5)` is impossible

Comment: Read up on operators and if constructs. You are using =< which doesn't exist, its <=, also you probably want to use &&/|| instead of &/|.

Comment: In my IDE `=<` is not recognized as a valid operator, use `<=` instead...

Comment: Give temperature(C): -22
Give wind velocity(km/h): 1
The wind chill temperature is : -34.4774

working fine for above inputs

Comment: This code doesn't compile, so you can't possibly be hitting the "else". Are you running a previously-compiled version of the code?

Comment: I have edited the question now its working fine without any compilation issues.

Comment: @Hades I doubt that, because of the `t=<5` and `v=<3`. Don't edit the code, as that materially changes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (((t>=-50) & (t=<5)) | 3>=v)
```

is all wrong:

- `&` and `|` are [bitwise operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). What you want is `&&` and `||` which are [Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)
- Logical operators allowed are : ==, != , > , >=  , <  , <= (See documentation [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)). You `(t=<5)` doesn't exist, what you want is `(t<=5)`

In the end, your `if` statement should be :

```
if (((t >= -50) && (t <= 5)) || 3 >= v)
```

Comment: you miss the `=<`

Comment: *`&&` and `|`* you forgot the second `|`

Comment: Both `&` and `|` can also be used as logical operators. The difference is that they are _not_ short-circuiting whereas `&&` and `||` are. There's also `^` which is XOR.

Comment: @Slaw i added a link to the official documentation

Comment: Thought I'd just mention it since a lot (all?) of the answers/comments are suggesting the OP **needs** to use `&&` instead of `&` and `||` instead of `|`. Using `&` and `|` will actually work but it's _better/recommended_ to use `&&` and `||` (except for the rare times you don't want the short-circuiting behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Yo have many mistakes both `if-conditions` in your code .

1. You used `&` instead of `&&` and `|` instead of `||`  .
2. You used `=<` instead of `<=` .

Modified code :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {// TempOut {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // variable
        double t;
        double v;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // inputs
        System.out.print("Give temperature(C): ");
        t = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Give wind velocity(km/h): ");
        v = input.nextDouble();

        // formula
        if ((t >= -50 && t <= 5) || (3 >= v)) // not if (((t>=-50) & (t=<5)) | 3>=v)
        {
            double formula = 13.12 + (2 * (0.6251 * t)) - (11.37 * v) + ((0.3965 * t) * v);
            System.out.print("The wind chill temperature is : " + formula);
        } else {
            if (((t < -50) && (t > 5)) || v <= 3) // not if (((t<-50) & (t>5)) | v=<3)
            {
                System.out.print("Formula not suitable");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Invalid input");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure that you do not make **syntax** errors.

Output :-

```
Give temperature(C): 2
Give wind velocity(km/h): 5
The wind chill temperature is : -37.26459999999999
```

Comment: Actually, `&` and `|` work just fine in boolean conditions they're just not the shortcut versions. There may be cases where you want to not use the shortcuts but those are probably rare. One of the more serious logic problems is `(t < -50) && (t > 5)` - which just can't happen and probably should be `(t < -50) || (t > 5)` instead (as a negation of `(t>=-50) && (t=<5)`)

Answer (score 0):

**Correct code:**

```
if (((t>=-50) & (t>=5)) | 3>=v) 
        {
            double formula = 13.12 + (2*(0.6251*t)) - (11.37*v) + ((0.3965*t)*v);
            System.out.print("The wind chill temperature is : "+formula);
        }
        else {
            if (((t<-50) & (t>5)) | v>=3) 
            {
            System.out.print("Formula not suitable");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("Invalid input");
            }
        }
```

You are using
if (((t>=-50) & (t=<5)) | **3>=v**) and if (((t<-50) & (t>5)) | **v=<3**) .

Look carefully this condition(Bold Cheractor) in correct code and your code.